# How do they power the fridge in the Going Merry?

Tags: one-piece

When the crew (Sanji and Ussop) saw the Arc Maxim powered by Enel's Lightning they were surprised by how the machine worked autonomously without a power source. But then how does the crew power the fridge?

Comment: You don't _actually_ need electricity to power a fridge.  Electricity is just used to power a couple of motors (plus other features, if you have a fancy one).  Really, all you need is something to drive the compressors, which usually amounts to a rotary motion source - a regular crank will do.  In the Sunny, it's clear they have rotary power.  However, it's possible the Going Merry doesn't have a refrigerator, but instead has an [ice box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icebox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although nothing related to electricity/fridges is mentioned in text in the [Wikia article on Going Merry](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Going_Merry?file=Going_Merry%2527s_Bathroom_and_Water-Drawing_Machine_Layout.png), you can find the following image there (with a rough Japanese counterpart [here](http://www.thegrandline.com/images/gmbathroom.jpg)):

> [image]

Presumably, this *Water-Drawing Machine* is used to power the refrigerator. As pointed out in the comments, all you need is a rotary motion source to use electricity at all times.

Although, the crew stores most of their food in the Storage Room, as indicated by this image:

> [image]

You may also note that there are 3 orange trees, taken from Bellamere's plantation, which are used as a source of emergency food:

> [image]

Comment: So wouldn't they need to constantly pedal?

Comment: Don't forget the real emergency food, Chopper!

Comment: @solalito that was indeed agood one. And Ashish where is this shown. I mean is this from the Manga? As currently I only watch the Anime. Or is it some form of a reference book?

Comment: @TheRanger Like I said, they may be using some sort of a rotary device. It's also possible that they don't use electricity for most part at all, and just store food in the storage room. As for the pictures, Oda explained the various schematics and explanations of each part of the ship in Volume 11 of the Manga. [Here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_11) is a link to the SBS, with the details on the Going Merry page. You can also check [this](http://www.thegrandline.com/luffyship.html) for detailed info about Going Merry with the Japanese counterparts of these images.